# WPF & Ribbon Control Accessibility Support

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, accessibility, ribbon

When developing applications using Windows Forms, you can specify property values for AccessibleName, and AccessibleDescription (among others). This is pretty neat, as you can control everything that goes on in your App with voice commands if your version of Windows has Windows Speech Recognition installed (or equivelant).

But, one thing I can't seem to find is this same support for Ribbon controls within WPF Applications.

I have searched Google and MSDN. But I cannot find any Accessibility stuff for WPF. Is it called something else in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF uses attached properties for this same purpose, which are defined in the [AutomationProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.aspx) class.

A detailed overview of the various aspects can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms747327.aspx), but you are probably looking for this [section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752056.aspx#Localization).

Comment: Thank you @CodeNaked. That was just what I'm after. Especially the Localization section.